# ActiveX Command Button Stops working when Excel is closed and then reopened

Tags: excel, vba, activex, designmode

I am not the most experienced with vba so forgive me...
I am currently working on some code that automates and captures data from an Omicron Program. This involves one active-x command button that once clicked commences the entire code.

The command button works and the code executes exactly how I want it to, but...
Once I close and reopen excel I get the error

> "Can't exit design mode because Control `CommandButton1` can not be
>   created."

A little odd considering it was working moments before. If I copy the work sheets and code to a new work book then everything begins to work again... until I close and reopen excel.

From a quick google search I haven't found a successful solution. I did try the following recommended steps:

1. Close all Excel documents
2. Open a blank document
3. Excel options > Trust center settings>macro settings>Select{Disable all macros with notifications}
4. Active X settings >
5. Select either:

   Disable all controls without notifications
   Prompt me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions
   Apply all settings and close.
6. Open the affected file and check allow the prompt to enable macros if required.

Found: https://superuser.com/questions/862168/cant-exit-design-mode-because-control-xxxx-can-not-be-created

This did not help.

Comment: The link in the question you linked probably solves the problem (delete the .exd files) https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500258/10223558 . You could also just add a custom ribbon, which IMO is a much cleaner more professional method.

Comment: Unfortunately, upon removing the .exd files I received the same error.